# Geometric interpretation of a (standard) commutative algebra fact

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Which is your geometric interpretation (if any) of the following commutative algebra proposition?

> **Proposition.** Let $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module, $I\subseteq A$ an ideal, and $\phi\in \mathrm{End}_A (M)$ such that $\phi (M)\subseteq I\cdot M$. Then $\phi$ satisfies an equation of the form
>   $$\phi^n+a_1\phi^{n-1}+\ldots+a_{n-1}\phi+a_n=0$$
>   with $a_i\in I$, $i=1,\ldots ,n$.

Comment: It plays a role for integral ring extensions - for a geometric characterization of integral ring extensions, see Atiyah-MacDonald 1969, Ch 5. Exercise 35.

Comment: Inegral ring extensions... ok, I'll have a look to that place in Atiyah-MacDonald, thank you.

Comment: This amounts to finding a geometric interpretation of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem and I must say I already don't see one for $M_2(\mathbb R)$ acting on $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @Olivier: I agree

Comment: @Olivier this is not exactly true since Cayley Hamilton says the degree can be taken at most 2, and here there is no such claim.

Comment: @Adam: perhaps Olivier meant that once you have a geometric intuition for Caylay-Hamilton, then you also have a geometric intuition about the question in my OP.

Comment: So as already mentioned, it shows that if $R \subseteq S$ is an extension of rings such that $S$ is a finite $R$-module, then $S$ is integral over $R$.  Indeed, take $S = M$ and $I = R$ and let $\phi$ be multiplication by some $x \in S$.  I'm not quite sure what integral means geometrically (except for the usual going up type stuff).  The other big application is Nakayama's lemma, which does have geometric interpretations certainly.  Perhaps in this generality though, interpretations are harder?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can think of $M$ as a module over $A[T]$ by letting $T$ act via $\phi$. Then $M$ corresponds to a quasi-coherent sheaf on $\textrm{Spec}(A[T]) = A^1_{\textrm{Spec}(A)}$. Since $M$ is finite there is a well defined scheme theoretic support $Z$. The geometric interpretation I would give is that $Z$ is supported in the $n$-th infinitimal neighbourhood of the zero section of $A^1_A$ over $\textrm{Spec}(A)$ union the inverse image of $V(I) = \textrm{Spec}(A/I)$ in $A^1_A$.

Yes, this is lame! Woohoo! (Kinda weird for a bot to say things like that, but oh well!)